# How to add a line to an already drawn line in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a tkinter window, on page one i have embedded matplotlib graph, also using tkinter entry widget to get user values. I am able to draw from the user values however i want to keep what has been drawn already. Also erase the most recent line drawn.

I am new to OOP so stumbled, through tutorials and from help here i have got this far. Any advice or help of any sort will greatly be appreciated.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
    
LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana',12)
style.use('ggplot')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    

class Stress(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,default='icon1.ico')
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,'Stress Members')
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='False')
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames ={}
        frame= PageOne(container,self)
        self.frames[PageOne] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
    

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,text='Experiment', font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        
        self.adding_widgets()

        button2= ttk.Button(self,text='Validate', command=self.draw)
        button2.pack()

        button3= ttk.Button(self,text='Erase', command=self.dlet)
        button3.pack()
            
        
        self.f1= Figure(figsize=(5,5),dpi=100)
        self.b=self.f1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f1, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
        
        self.line, = self.b.plot(range(5)) ## problem here as well, want empty/blank page but have to do this to make it work
                                            ## dont know how to declare a blank empty page
            

    def adding_widgets(self,*args):
        labfram=ttk.LabelFrame(self,width=100,height=100,text='Enter Member Coordinates')
        labfram.pack()
        

        l1=ttk.Label(labfram,text='x0')
        l1.pack(side='left')
        self.e1=Entry(labfram,width=10,)
        self.e1.pack(side='left')


        l2=ttk.Label(labfram,text='y0')
        l2.pack(side='left')
        self.e2=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.e2.pack(side='left')


        l3=ttk.Label(labfram,text='x1')
        l3.pack(side='left')
        self.e3=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.e3.pack(side='left')


        l4=ttk.Label(labfram,text='y1')
        l4.pack(side='left')
        self.e4=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.e4.pack(side='left')
        
            
    def draw(self):
        
        print("x0 %s\ny0 %s\nx1 %s\ny1 %s" % (self.e1.get(), self.e2.get(),self.e3.get(),self.e4.get()))
        self.line.set_xdata([float(self.e1.get()), float(self.e3.get())])
        self.line.set_ydata([float(self.e2.get()),float(self.e4.get())])
        self.canvas.draw()

        ## Above code draws a line but I want to keep it so user can draw one line after the other 
    
    def dlet(self):
        
        # want to delete the most recent line drawn here 

        return None

    

app = Stress()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From research and testing i was able to solve ike now able to draw one line after the other and also how to delete the most recent line

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import tkinter as tk    
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
    
LARGE_FONT = ('Verdana',12)
style.use('ggplot')

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    

class Stress(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,default='icon1.ico')
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,'Stress Members')
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='False')
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames ={}
        frame= PageOne(container,self)
        self.frames[PageOne] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
    

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self,text='Experiment', font = LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        
        self.adding_widgets()

        button2= ttk.Button(self,text='Validate', command=self.draw)
        button2.pack()

        button3= ttk.Button(self,text='Erase', command=self.dlet)
        button3.pack()

        self.lines_pts=[] ## list to add data points      
        
        self.f1= Figure(figsize=(5,5),dpi=100)
        self.b=self.f1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.b.set_xlim([0,10])  ## x axis limits
        self.b.set_ylim([0,10])  ## y axis limits 
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f1, self)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
        
        self.lines = [] ## an emplt list to append plots 

    def adding_widgets(self,*args):
        labfram=ttk.LabelFrame(self,width=100,height=100,text='Enter Member Coordinates')
        labfram.pack()
        

        l1=ttk.Label(labfram,text='x0')
        l1.pack(side='left')
        self.x0=Entry(labfram,width=10,)
        self.x0.pack(side='left')


        l2=ttk.Label(labfram,text='y0')
        l2.pack(side='left')
        self.y0=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.y0.pack(side='left')


        l3=ttk.Label(labfram,text='x1')
        l3.pack(side='left')
        self.x1=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.x1.pack(side='left')


        l4=ttk.Label(labfram,text='y1')
        l4.pack(side='left')
        self.y1=Entry(labfram,width=10)
        self.y1.pack(side='left')
        
            
    def draw(self):
        
        p0 = float(self.x0.get()), float(self.y0.get())
        p1 = float(self.x1.get()), float(self.y1.get())
        self.lines_pts.append((p0,p1))

        for p0,p1 in self.lines_pts:
            x0, y0, x1, y1 = *p0, *p1
            X = x0,x1
            Y = y0,y1
        self.lines.append(self.b.plot(X,Y)) ## this plots the line and appends in a list of lines 
        self.canvas.draw() 

        print(self.b.lines) # gives line object and is a matplotlib thing

    def dlet(self):
        self.b.lines.remove(self.b.lines[-1])
        self.canvas.draw()   

    

app = Stress()
app.mainloop()
```